# How do I get my labels in the open_file methods to stay and not disappear?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

In my code I'm very confused why on button press my labels disappear after the next button press. What I'm trying to do is get the file path + file name to stay on the interface after button click

The first part goes over the open_file commands that will operate on button click. The next part goes over the file labels, and the final part are the actual buttons.

```
# Import the required libraries
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os

# Create an instance of tkinter frame or window
win = Tk()

# Set the geometry of tkinter frame
win.geometry("700x350")

# Choose a Trace File window
def open_file():
    file = fd.askopenfilename(parent=win, title='Choose a Trace File')
    print(win.splitlist(file))
# Display file path
    file_label.config(text=file)
    file_label.place(relx = 0.59, rely = 0.77)

    # Display file name
    fullpath = file
    just_the_name = os.path.basename(fullpath)
    file_label2.config(text=just_the_name)
    file_label2.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0.8)
    
# Choose a Supplementary File window
def open_file2():
   file = fd.askopenfilename(parent=win, title='Choose a Supplementary File')
   print(win.splitlist(file))
   file_label.config(text=file)
   file_label.place(relx = 0.59, rely = 0.77)
      
   fullpath = file
   just_the_name = os.path.basename(fullpath)
   file_label2.config(text=just_the_name)
   file_label2.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0.8)

# File Path and File Name labels
file_label = Label(win, text="")
file_label.pack()
file_label2 = Label(win, text="")
file_label2.pack()

# Add a Button Widget
# Add file path and file name next to button when clicked
btn1 = ttk.Button(win, text="Select the Trace File", command=open_file).pack()
btn2 = ttk.Button(win, text="Select the Supplementary File", command=open_file2).pack()
btn3 = ttk.Button(win, text="Select the Output File", command=convert_file).pack()

win.mainloop()
```

I would appreciate any help in trying to figure out how to get these labels to stick.

Comment: why do you use `place()`?  You already put `Label` in window using `pack()` and you don't have to change. Besides, it can move label in wrong place and you may not see this label.

Comment: BTW: you make common mistake. `btn = Button(...).pack()` assigns `None` to `var` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` always return `None`. If you need variable `btn` then you have to do it in two steps `btn = Button(...)` and `btn.pack()`. And if you don't use variable `btn` then you can skip variable `Button(...).pack()`

Comment: I don't know if Inderstand your problem but code `.config(text=file)` is for replacing text on label. If you want to keep previous value on label then you have to add new text to previous text - `file_label["text"] =  file_label["text"] + file`. OR you have to create new `Label` with new text and add it to window. OR at start you should create more labels - two labels for every button - and every button should show text in own labels. `Label` doesn't work like `print()` - it doesn't append new text to previous text but it replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Both buttons use the same labels to display path - so second button replace previous value.

If you want to keep text then every button needs own labels.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import os

# --- functions ---

def open_file1():
    filename = fd.askopenfilename(parent=win, title='Choose a Trace File')

    if filename:  # check if pressed button `Cancel`
        full_path = os.path.basename(filename)

        file1_name.config(text=filename)
        file1_full_path.config(text=full_path)
    
def open_file2():
    filename = fd.askopenfilename(parent=win, title='Choose a Supplementary File')

    if filename:  # check if pressed button `Cancel`
        full_path = os.path.basename(filename)

        file2_name.config(text=filename)
        file2_full_path.config(text=full_path)

# --- main ---

win = tk.Tk()

#win.geometry("700x350")

# --- labels for first button ---

file1_name = tk.Label(win, text="")
file1_name.pack()

file1_full_path = tk.Label(win, text="")
file1_full_path.pack()

# --- labels for second button ---

file2_name = tk.Label(win, text="")
file2_name.pack()

file2_full_path = tk.Label(win, text="")
file2_full_path.pack()

# --- buttons ---

ttk.Button(win, text="Select the Trace File",         command=open_file1).pack(fill='x')
ttk.Button(win, text="Select the Supplementary File", command=open_file2).pack(fill='x')

win.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

Eventually you should get previous text from label, add new text to this text, and set new text in label.

```
    previous_text = file_name.cget("text")
    new_text = previous_text + filename + '\n'
    file_name.config(text=new_text)
    
    previous_text = file_full_path.cget("text")
    new_text = previous_text + full_path + '\n'
    file_full_path.config(text=new_text)
```

or shorter

```
    file_name["text"] += filename + '\n'
    file_full_path["text"] += full_path + '\n'
```

But this way it will display all selected files - and always new file at the end (and it doesn't matter which button you use) - so it could be more useful as history of all selected files.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

# --- functions ---

def open_file1():
    filename = fd.askopenfilename(parent=win, title='Choose a Trace File')

    if filename:
        full_path = os.path.basename(filename)

        previous_text = file_name.cget("text")
        new_text = previous_text + filename + '\n'
        file_name.config(text=new_text)
        
        previous_text = file_full_path.cget("text")
        new_text = previous_text + full_path + '\n'
        file_full_path.config(text=new_text)

        # shorter        
        #file_name["text"] += filename + '\n'
        #file_full_path["text"] += full_path + '\n'
    
# Choose a Supplementary File window
def open_file2():
    filename = fd.askopenfilename(parent=win, title='Choose a Supplementary File')

    if filename:
        full_path = os.path.basename(filename)

        previous_text = file_name.cget("text")
        new_text = previous_text + filename + '\n'
        file_name.config(text=new_text)
        
        previous_text = file_full_path.cget("text")
        new_text = previous_text + full_path + '\n'
        file_full_path.config(text=new_text)

        # shorter        
        #file_name["text"] += filename + '\n'
        #file_full_path["text"] += full_path + '\n'

# --- main ---

win = tk.Tk()

#win.geometry("700x350")

# --- labels ---

file_name = tk.Label(win, text="")
file_name.pack()

file_full_path = tk.Label(win, text="")
file_full_path.pack()

# --- buttons ---

ttk.Button(win, text="Select the Trace File",         command=open_file1).pack(fill='x')
ttk.Button(win, text="Select the Supplementary File", command=open_file2).pack(fill='x')

win.mainloop()
```

[image]